# Minecraft /testfor problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have another problem with my Minecraft PvP map. I'm trying to set up a command block that checks when a player is standing on a block and if so it will give them jump boost so I used this command `/testfor @a[x=621,y=80,z=452,r=1]` but it says '`The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format`' and I don't know what to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you can't use **/testfor** to find people in exact locations, but what you can do is have a command block below and do a **/testfor @a[r=3]** and that will check for players in a radius of 3 blocks from that command block.

Comment: This isn't exactly correct.  You can define a box using `[x=,y=,z=,dx=,dy=,dz=]`.  It's just harder to do than specifying a radius, since you need to know the exact coords of where you're testing.

Comment: You **can** use `/testfor` to locate a player at a specific coordinate and Joe's command is in the correct syntax to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want it to activate more than once? If you don't I recommend hooking it up to a command block that replace the one with /testfor to be replaced by air:

```
/fill x1 y1 z1 x2 y2 z2 minecraft:air
```